# Issues in the Image timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to built a timer for my Image Slider as it is in this site
https://store.sap.com/sap/cpa/repository/store/sapstore/US/default.html

This is the one which I tried of my own. 
Image with text is sliding good, but there is issue in my timer.
But there are some issues due to that I commented that code in my tried link:

http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9c/24

Here I created a thumbnails but the issue is binding the image and its text with this timer.

Comment: I've not understend what you want? the image is not loaded in sync with the text?

Comment: @Alex Ball: Hi yes its one issue and at the same time, if you check this site https://store.sap.com/sap/cpa/repository/store/sapstore/US/default.html Here you found the image slider with a timer on it. I was trying to creating that timer but I am unable to get it. In my demo I commented that code which I tried for the timer

Comment: to start immediatly with slider, add Slider();to the end of: $(function() { //Local XML Data, to not wait the setInterval first call. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've generated li based on images length:

```
for(var i = 0; i< maximages; i++){   
    var th = '<li><a href="#'+i+'"></a></li>';
    $(th).appendTo('#thumbs > ul');
}
```

and add a click function on li (is not perfect but it's an idea to do):

```
$('.paging >li a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log(e.target.href);
    var slide = e.target.href.split('#')[1];
    console.log(slide);
    prevIndex = slide; //set next slide to index clicked
});
```

an animate the thumbs:

```
$('.paging > li').eq(prevIndex-1).css('background-color', '#777777');
$('.paging > li').eq(prevIndex).css('background-color', '#FF0');
```

More effect should be done with Jquery UI.

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UgQJG/)

I'm sorry, but now i've no much time to test it, but hope this help.